# Traffic light program. Java. Loops

Tags: java, loops, methods

My code is getting complicated and it doesn't seem to be getting resolved, please, have a look and give me advice.
Please, make sure you do not share a solution as I'd rather fix it by me, instead of leaving it unclear.
Here we go:

TASK:
The pedestrian traffic light is programmed as follows:
at the beginning of each hour, the green signal is on for three minutes,
then the signal is yellow for one minute,
and then it is red for one minute.
Then the light is green again for three minutes, etc.
Use the keyboard to enter a real number t that represents the number of minutes that have elapsed since the beginning of the hour.
Determine what color the traffic light is at the specified time.
Display the result as follows:
"green" if the light is green,
"yellow" if the light is yellow, and
"red" if the light is red.

EXAMPLE:
For 2.5 - Green.
For 3 - Yellow.
For 5 - Green.
and so on, within 60 minutes loop.

MY CODE:

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
    
     BufferedReader sum = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
     double a;
    
    a = Double.parseDouble(sum.readLine());
    
    while(true) {
     calcYellow(a, a); break;}
    while(true) {
     calcRed(a, a); break;}
    while(true) {
     calcGreen(a, a, a, a); break;}

    }
    
    static void calcYellow(double a, double b) {
      double a1 = 3.0;
      double b1 = 3.5;
    for (a=a1+4; a<60; a++);
    for (b=b1+4; b<60; b++);
      if ((a%3.0==0) || (a%3.5==0));
      if ((b%3.0==0) || (b%3.5==0));
    
    System.out.println("Yellow");
      }

    static void calcRed(double a, double b) {
      double a1 = 4.0;
      double b1 = 4.5;
    for (a=a1+4; a<60; a++);
    for (b=b1+4; b<60; b++);
    if ((a%4.0==0) && (a%4.5==0));
    if ((b%4.0==0) && (b%4.5==0));
    
    System.out.println("Red");
    }

    static void calcGreen(double a, double b, double c, double d) {
    double a1 = 1.0;
    double b1 = 1.5;
    double c1 = 2.0;
    double d1 = 2.5;
    for (a=a1+4; a<60; a++);
    for (b=b1+4; b<60; b++);
    for (c=c1+4; c<60; c++);
    for (d=d1+4; d<60; d++);
    
    System.out.println("Green");
}       
    }
```

Any advice will be highly appreciated.
TY in Advance!

Comment: An obvious logic flaw is having 3 while loops each calling `calcSomeColor`. There should be a method that converts the input (time) into one of the three possible outputs. Not three methods converting the input always to the output (which can't happen for all inputs).

Comment: What is the point of `while(true) { calcYellow(a, a); break; }`? It's a forever loop that always exits after the first iteration, i.e. it's not looping at all. It's exactly the same as not having the loop: `calcYellow(a, a);`

Comment: What is the point of `for (a=a1+4; a<60; a++);`? It's a loop that iterates some times, but doesn't do anything in the loop, and it will run so fast it's not even a delay. --- What is the point of `if ((a%3.0==0) || (a%3.5==0));`? It's an `if` statement, the it doesn't control anything. --- In both cases, you probably meant to do those with the `;` at the end.

Comment: Is it a special requirement to calculate the color using loops?  You can do the same by calculating a remainder after division by 5 and checking the range of the result.

Comment: You're right Andreas, I should have left the comments. sorry, I'll update it very soon. Kayaman, thank you for your advice - I'll try to take it into consideration.

Comment: The biggest immediate problem: use meaningful variable names. Using single char variable names like you do renders your code totally unreadable.

Comment: Thank you @GhostCat, your advice made full sense. As far as the solution has already been posted, the question is closed and next time I won't ask the question posting the code like that one.                                                                                                                                 Actually, thank's to all of you guys, really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Solution could be as easy as this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader sum = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        double enteredTime;
        enteredTime = Double.parseDouble(sum.readLine());

        double colorTime = enteredTime % 5;

        if (colorTime >= 0 && colorTime < 3) {
            System.out.println("Green");
        } else if (colorTime >= 3 && colorTime < 4) {
            System.out.println("Yellow");
        } else if (colorTime >= 4 && colorTime < 5) {
            System.out.println("Red");
        }


    }
```

You could expand this with the 60 minutes loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array of colors imitating their sequence and calculate the index in the array using remainder operation.

Also, an edge case may need to be handled when the timestamp is negative, that is, you need to define the traffic light color in the *past*: from 1 minute "ago" it was red, from 2 till 1 minutes it was yellow and so on.

```java
private static final String[] COLORS_BY_MINUTE = {"Green", "Green", "Green", "Yellow", "Red"};

public static String getColor(double minute) {
    double colorIndex = minute % COLORS_BY_MINUTE.length;
    // handle "backward"/negative timestamp
    if (colorIndex < 0) {
        colorIndex += COLORS_BY_MINUTE.length;
    }
    return COLORS_BY_MINUTE[(int) colorIndex];
}

// tests
double[] tests = { -3.5, -2.5, -1.5, -1, 0, 1.5, 2.5, 3, 3.8, 4.5, 5.5, 62.5 };
Arrays.stream(tests)
      .forEach(t -> System.out.printf("%4.1f -> %s%n", t, getColor(t)));
```

Output:

```
-3.5 -> Green
-2.5 -> Green
-1.5 -> Yellow
-1.0 -> Red
 0.0 -> Green
 1.5 -> Green
 2.5 -> Green
 3.0 -> Yellow
 3.8 -> Yellow
 4.5 -> Red
 5.5 -> Green
62.5 -> Green
```

Comment: That's an amazing one, @Alex Rudenko. I'll try this solution as well, thank you!